# how to split background of <div> into 3 solid colors from left to right using linear gradient?

Tags: html, css

From left to right:

40% - Green
20% - Blue
40% - Red

The colors must be solid, i.e. no gradient.

I am not sure how to use the percentages in the correct way to make it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that solid color behavior, specify starting and ending points of each color, setting the starting point of next color on top of the ending point of previous color. (0 - 40% for green, 40% - 60% for blue, 60% - 100% for red).

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg,
     rgba(0,255,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 40%,
     rgba(0,0,255,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 60%,
     rgba(255,0,0,1) 60%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%
);
```

P.S. [CSS Gradient](https://cssgradient.io/) is a great website if you want to see how gradients work.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you're aiming for (html is `<div></div>`)?

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
      green  40%, 
      blue   40%, 
      blue   60%, 
      red 60%, 
      red 100%
      
  );
}
```

https://codepen.io/zlietzau/pen/powgamK